# How to convert given time to cron expression using quartz api in java?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

How to convert Given time to cron expression.

i.e. 
example given time

scheduled day="mon,tue" time="11.00" timeinterval="3" type="Weekly" to cron expression.

A solution to this question will really appreciated and very helpful for me.

Comment: try http://www.cronmaker.com/ to generate cron expression.

Comment: My requirement is I dynamically get given time from User interface and I need to convert it into Cron Expression.Is there any pre existing code.

Answer (score 3):

How about writing simple function [using](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Format)

```
public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        System.out.println(toCron(String.valueOf(dateTime.getMinute()),
                String.valueOf(dateTime.getHour()),
                String.valueOf(dateTime.getDayOfMonth()),
                String.valueOf(dateTime.getMonth()),
                String.valueOf(dateTime.getDayOfWeek()), String.valueOf(dateTime.getYear())));
    }


    public static String toCron(final String mins, final String hrs, final String dayOfMonth, final String month, final String dayOfWeek, final String year) {
        return String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s", mins, hrs, dayOfMonth, month, dayOfWeek, year);
    }
}
```